# Visual Studio 2015 SSRS - Report Preview Shows Invisible Values

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I am developing SSRS reports in Visual Studio 2015. This happened before in the SQL Report Builder.

When I try and preview the report is doesnt show any of the value. However exporting the report does show the values.

This is really annoying as I have to export the report to see my results.

Has anyone come across this or have a possible solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thought that comes to mind is the data cache issue.  Have you tried:

1) Clicking the "Refresh" button on the report after it is ran because I believe that refreshes the data cache

2) Via File Explorer navigate to where the .rdl file is and find the .data file for the report and delete it then run the report.

3) As per the comments below: In VS2015 just clean the project, it deletes the .data files.

Comment: or in VS2015 just clean the project, it deletes the .data files.

Comment: I have done all three tasks mention above. Still no luck. I have found a work around by viewing the preview in PRINT LAYOUT. But would rather find a reason and solution.

Comment: Well, I am stumped.  Have you tried running the report through Report Builder to see if it also does that?  Are there expressions changing font colors or the like?

Comment: I have not yet tried using the Report Builder. But I want to manage the reporting project correctly (with TFS) using VS2015. No expressions to change colors. A new report will work fine, then suddenly the preview shows blank. Its like the rendering of the report is incomplete.

Comment: I get that and it makes sense but trying report builder would help let us know if it's possibly something in vs or the report.